# Загрузка изображения без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: загрузка, ajax, изображения

Здравствуйте. Скажите, как загрузить изображение на сайт без перезагрузки страницы. Мне это нужно для последующей вырезки миниатюры из загруженного изображения. То есть сейчас имеется плагин для выделения фрагмента изображения, но изображение ведь предварительно должно быть загружено на сервер, а потом уже можно с ним проводить какие то манипуляции (поправьте если я ошибаюсь). Нужно что бы пользователь выбрал изображение, оно загрузилось как бы в фоновом режиме, затем уже из загруженного изображения пользователь будет вырезать миниатюру. 
Пробовал Jquery Form upload (http://malsup.com/jquery/form/), что то не получается, сделал форму

```
<form id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="../profile/edit">
    <input type="file" name="test" />
    <input type="submit" value="Тест"/>
</form>
```

прописал

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() {

    });
});
```

а вот что дальше писать в js не знаю. Если кто работал с этим плагином, то помогите пожалуйста разобраться

Answer (score 1):

Допустим у нас на сайтике `php` скрипт, содержащий вырезку миниатюры:

```
$uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$uploadfile_min = $uploaddir . 'min_' .  basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    resize_image($uploadfile, $uploadfile_min);
    echo 'min_' .  basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
}
```

А на страничке пишем:

```
$('#myForm').ajaxForm({
    success: function(data) {
        $('#image').attr('src', data);
    }
});
```

Comment: при нажатии на кнопку формы (отправить) в консоли: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) http://localhost/test/%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%3Chtml%3E%20%20%20%20%3Chead%3E…Input").change(function(){readURL(this);    });</script>    </body></html>